# nginx reverse_proxy from location to specific URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

i'm new to nginx. I've got nginx and a python webserver that listen on ports :5000.

I wanna do something like that www.example.com/berlin and want to get the data from 127.0.0.1/?lat=*berlin*&lon=*berlin*

I don't know how to set a query string which is used if i request the location.

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        }

        location /berlin/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/?lat=52.5185931&lon=13.3941181/;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/?lat=$1&lon=$1;
    }
}
```

The second location block captures the "berlin" if example.com/berlin is reqested and than this is passed to the websever as query params.

But please note that this seems to be a pretty bad idea since this would match anything that is not requesting your home page (`/`). Thus, even requesting example.com/index.html would be passed to the webserver as /?lat=index.html&lon=index.html. You could prevent this by using some sort of prefix like example.com/city/berlin or by improving the regex of the second location block to not match certain things like index.html